# Core Media code Objective C to Swift translation does not work

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I am trying to follow the example of the AAPLTimedAnnotationWriter example on GitHub (https://github.com/robovm/apple-ios-samples/blob/master/AVTimedAnnotationWriterUsingCustomAnnotationMetadataforMovieWritingandPlayback/AVTimedAnnotationWriter/AAPLTimedAnnotationWriter.m) and implement something similar in my Swift 5.7 code (running on macOS).

Specifically, I ran into issues in translating line #208-218 of the example code.

```
CMFormatDescriptionRef metadataFormatDescription = NULL;
NSArray *specs = @[
                    @{(__bridge NSString *)kCMMetadataFormatDescriptionMetadataSpecificationKey_Identifier : AAPLTimedAnnotationWriterCircleCenterCoordinateIdentifier,
                        (__bridge NSString *)kCMMetadataFormatDescriptionMetadataSpecificationKey_DataType : (__bridge NSString *)kCMMetadataBaseDataType_PointF32},
                    @{(__bridge NSString *)kCMMetadataFormatDescriptionMetadataSpecificationKey_Identifier : AAPLTimedAnnotationWriterCircleRadiusIdentifier,
                        (__bridge NSString *)kCMMetadataFormatDescriptionMetadataSpecificationKey_DataType : (__bridge NSString *)kCMMetadataBaseDataType_Float64},
                    @{(__bridge NSString *)kCMMetadataFormatDescriptionMetadataSpecificationKey_Identifier : AAPLTimedAnnotationWriterCommentFieldIdentifier,
                        (__bridge NSString *)kCMMetadataFormatDescriptionMetadataSpecificationKey_DataType : (__bridge NSString *)kCMMetadataBaseDataType_UTF8}];


OSStatus err = CMMetadataFormatDescriptionCreateWithMetadataSpecifications(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCMMetadataFormatType_Boxed, (__bridge CFArrayRef)specs, &metadataFormatDescription);
```

My code:

```
private func createChapterMetadataFormatDescription() -> CMMetadataFormatDescription? {
    let extra: NSArray = [
        (
            kCMMetadataFormatDescriptionMetadataSpecificationKey_Identifier: "mdta/com.example.circle.center.coordinate",
            kCMMetadataFormatDescriptionMetadataSpecificationKey_DataType: kCMMetadataBaseDataType_PointF32
        ),
        (
            kCMMetadataFormatDescriptionMetadataSpecificationKey_Identifier: "mdta/com.example.circle.radius",
            kCMMetadataFormatDescriptionMetadataSpecificationKey_DataType: kCMMetadataBaseDataType_Float64
        ),
        (
            kCMMetadataFormatDescriptionMetadataSpecificationKey_Identifier: "mdta/com.example.comment.field",
            kCMMetadataFormatDescriptionMetadataSpecificationKey_DataType: kCMMetadataBaseDataType_UTF8
        )
    ]

    var formatDescription: CMMetadataFormatDescription? = nil
    if kCVReturnSuccess != CMMetadataFormatDescriptionCreateWithMetadataSpecifications(allocator: kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                                       metadataType: kCMMetadataFormatType_Boxed,
                                                                                       metadataSpecifications: extra,
                                                                                       formatDescriptionOut: &formatDescription) { return nil }
    return formatDescription
}
```

The problem is, `CMMetadataFormatDescriptionCreateWithMetadataSpecifications()` call returned `kCMFormatDescriptionError_InvalidParameter` error.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that if I change my code to the following, the function would succeed.

```
    let item1: NSDictionary = [
        kCMMetadataFormatDescriptionMetadataSpecificationKey_Identifier: "mdta/com.example.circle.center.coordinate",
        kCMMetadataFormatDescriptionMetadataSpecificationKey_DataType: kCMMetadataBaseDataType_PointF32
    ]
    let item2: NSDictionary = [
        kCMMetadataFormatDescriptionMetadataSpecificationKey_Identifier: "mdta/com.example.circle.radius",
        kCMMetadataFormatDescriptionMetadataSpecificationKey_DataType: kCMMetadataBaseDataType_Float64
    ]
    let item3: NSDictionary = [
        kCMMetadataFormatDescriptionMetadataSpecificationKey_Identifier: "mdta/com.example.comment.field",
        kCMMetadataFormatDescriptionMetadataSpecificationKey_DataType: kCMMetadataBaseDataType_UTF8
    ]
    let extra: NSArray = [item1, item2, item3]

    ......
```

Not sure why, but maybe the dictionary literals were not properly converted to the format that Core Media was expecting.